# Spark on Linux Error: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, linux-mint

I'm on Chapter 2 of Learning Spark, Second Edition. When I go to execute the example mnmcont.py script I get the error below:

```
21/02/08 11:40:12 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=2, No such file or directory
```

The command I'm using to execute the script is:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit mnmcount.py data/mnm_dataset.csv
```

and I'm in the LearningSparkV2-master/chapter2/py/src directory

In my bashrc file I have added the following lines and sourced the file.

```
SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/spark"
alias python="python3"
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
```

The full code of the mnmcount.py script is below.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import count

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: mnmcount <file>", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(-1)

    spark = (SparkSession
        .builder
        .appName("PythonMnMCount")
        .getOrCreate())
    # get the M&M data set file name
    mnm_file = sys.argv[1]
    # read the file into a Spark DataFrame
    mnm_df = (spark.read.format("csv")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .load(mnm_file))
    mnm_df.show(n=5, truncate=False)

    # aggregate count of all colors and groupBy state and color
    # orderBy descending order
    count_mnm_df = (mnm_df.select("State", "Color", "Count")
                    .groupBy("State", "Color")
                    .sum("Count")
                    .orderBy("sum(Count)", ascending=False))

    # show all the resulting aggregation for all the dates and colors
    count_mnm_df.show(n=60, truncate=False)
    print("Total Rows = %d" % (count_mnm_df.count()))

    # find the aggregate count for California by filtering
    ca_count_mnm_df = (mnm_df.select("*")
                       .where(mnm_df.State == 'CA')
                       .groupBy("State", "Color")
                       .sum("Count")
                       .orderBy("sum(Count)", ascending=False))

    # show the resulting aggregation for California
    ca_count_mnm_df.show(n=10, truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
```

to bashrc the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

try set your master as "local[*]"

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).